# What type of column will support datetime with offset?

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp

During liquibase script execution I'm filling the table with data. Data has one column with the next value: 2017-10-03T07:11:00.0000000Z which I'm struggling with to parse into the column:

```
liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set /changelog/00000000000001.xml::00000000000001::IAmUser:
 Reason: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0000000Z"
```

I've tried multiple column types but none of them worked: datetime, datetime2, timestamp (datetimeoffset doesn't work with MySQL).

How can I parse this date into SQL column?

Answer (score 0):

Use `datetime(6)` / `timestamp(6)` where 6 is the precision for fractional seconds. Also, leave out the `Z` from the end of the date string.